# Keep the code together or split up?

Tags: split, titanium

I am building an app in Titanium studios, it's an childrens sound app.
Now i am going to have one sound/animal per window.
Is it better to split up the code(one(1) window per JS-file) on different js files or should I keep all the code in the same app.js?

Also; this is my first question on here so bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

All dependa how you want to design your app, how much code is reused between windows and how complex is it. In general it's good to split code between files but wait until it will.be big enouhh for refactoring.

Comment: Thanks :)
This is things that are good to know for newb programmers.
Alot of the code will be reused, so im thinking of keeping it in the same file. Maybe spilt it later on..

Comment: Rule of thumb is doing it in the easiest way possible and then evolve together with app. Don't overengineer it early.

Answer (score 0):

i would first recommend that you use Alloy which is the MVC framework for programming solutions with titanium. If you are using Alloy, you will see that it is one window per javascript file.

I would strongly urge you to review the Alloy documentation and develop you application following the best practices.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework

Comment: Yes, Alloy would be the best but this is for a school thingy so i am not aloud to use alloy..

But thanks anyway mister.